# how to construct a matrix from lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm new to Python and my problem is how to construct a matrix from some lists? For example if i have lists:

```
[388.625, 174.125, 157.25, 166.375]
[432.25, 606.125, 326.25, 202.75]
[383.5, 718.25, 630., 284.]
[487.375, 299.125, 438.125, 432.5]
```

How can i join them to create a matrix?

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on dataframes in Python here:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html

Comment: matrix = [[ 0.4691, -0.2829, -1.5091, -1.1356],
       [ 1.2121, -0.1732,  0.1192, -1.0442],
       [-0.8618, -2.1046, -0.4949,  1.0718],
       [ 0.7216, -0.7068, -1.0396,  0.2719],
       [-0.425 ,  0.567 ,  0.2762, -1.0874],
       [-0.6737,  0.1136, -1.4784,  0.525 ]]

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that by "matrix" you mean a 2-D `numpy` array,

```
import numpy
matrix = numpy.array(list_of_lists)
```

will do it, if in `list_of_lists` you have, guess what!, the list of lists of numbers.

If what you have is, e.g, four separate lists, each of four numbers, named `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, making a list of lists out of them isn't really all that hard...:

```
matrix = numpy.array([a, b, c, d])
```

and so forth, depending exactly on what you mean by "construct a matrix from some lists"!-)

Comment: Or `numpy.matrix(list_of_lists)`, since OP said "matrix".