# create a matrix from a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a list like this:

```
A=[["a_00",0,0],["a_01",0,1],["a_02",0,2],["a_03",0,3], ["a_10",1,0],["a_11",1,1],["a_12",1,2],["a_13",1,3], ["a_20",2,0],["a_21",2,1],["a_22",2,2],["a_23",2,3], ["a_30",3,0],["a_31",3,1],["a_32",3,2],["a_33",3,3]]
```

which yields:

```
In [187]: A
Out[187]:
[['a_00', 0, 0],
 ['a_01', 0, 1],
 ['a_02', 0, 2],
 ['a_03', 0, 3],
 ['a_10', 1, 0],
 ['a_11', 1, 1],
 ['a_12', 1, 2],
 ['a_13', 1, 3],
 ['a_20', 2, 0],
 ['a_21', 2, 1],
 ['a_22', 2, 2],
 ['a_23', 2, 3],
 ['a_30', 3, 0],
 ['a_31', 3, 1],
 ['a_32', 3, 2],
 ['a_33', 3, 3]]
```

i want to turn in to a matrix like this:

```
B=[["a_00","a_01","a_02","a_03"], ["a_10","a_11","a_12","a_13"], ["a_20","a_21","a_22","a_23"], ["a_30","a_31","a_32","a_33"]]
```

yields:

```
In [188]: B
Out[188]:
[['a_00', 'a_01', 'a_02', 'a_03'],
 ['a_10', 'a_11', 'a_12', 'a_13'],
 ['a_20', 'a_21', 'a_22', 'a_23'],
 ['a_30', 'a_31', 'a_32', 'a_33']]
```

i wrote this code for my purpose:

```
import numpy
B=numpy.zeros(7,7)
for item in A:
    B[item[1]][item[2]]=item[0]
```

but i see this error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

what should i do?

Comment: can you provide a small, but reproducible input data set and your desired data set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to construct a matrix from lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224148/how-to-construct-a-matrix-from-lists-in-python)

Comment: What are the types of `a_00`, `a_01` etc? String or numeric?

Comment: @MaxU: for example A=[["a_00",0,0],["a_01",0,1],["a_02",0,2],["a_03",0,3],
  ["a_10",1,0],["a_11",1,1],["a_12",1,2],["a_13",1,3],
  ["a_20",2,0],["a_21",2,1],["a_22",2,2],["a_23",2,3],
  ["a_30",3,0],["a_31",3,1],["a_32",3,2],["a_33",3,3]]

B=[["a_00","a_01","a_02","a_03"],
   ["a_10","a_11","a_12","a_13"],
   ["a_20","a_21","a_22","a_23"],
   ["a_30","a_31","a_32","a_33"]]

Comment: @Psidom: they are numbers but i think it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine except 1 line `B=numpy.zeros(7,7)` it should be `B=numpy.zeros((7,7))`

As per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

```
A=[[1,0,0],[2,0,1],[3,0,2],
[4,1,0],[5,1,1],[6,1,2],
[7,2,0],[8,2,1],[9,2,2]]

import numpy as np

B = np.zeros((3,3))
for item in A:
    B[item[1]][item[2]]=item[0]

B

array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

you can also do it in a simple way using reshape

```
np.array(A)[:,0].reshape(7,7)
```

How that works:

```
np.array(A)
array([[a_00, 0, 0],
       [a_01, 0, 1],
       [a_02, 0, 2],
       ...

np.array(A)[:,0]
array([a_00, a_01, a_02,...])

np.array(A)[:,0].reshape(3,3) # reshape it in the shape that we care for.
```

Comment: I would index the 2d array `B` with: `B[item[1], item[2]]`

Comment: @hpaulj cool. share reason also so I can understand better, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The list is stored in the format of a sparse matrix, you can extract the value, row and column index separately and then construct a sparse matrix from it using `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`:

```
lst = [[3,0,0],[2,0,1],[1,0,6],
       [5,1,0],[3,1,1],[2,1,6],
       [7,6,0],[5,6,1],[7,6,6]]

from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

v, i, j = zip(*lst)
coo_matrix((v, (i, j)), shape=(7,7)).toarray()

#array([[3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#       [5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```

---

Using @Vikash's data:

```
v, i, j = zip(*A)
coo_matrix((v, (i, j)), shape=(3,3)).toarray()
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: this is very elegant, but i believe OP wanted a different result set...

Comment: @MaxU Hmm. I just tested Vikash's data set as well. Seems to give the same result.

Comment: @Psidom: that's good but  its shape is not desirable for my purpose.

Comment: @MaxU zeros are entries when the index is missing from the array.

Comment: @mahsa What shape do you need? I guess you can always specify the shape to your desired one by changing the `shape` parameter in `coo_matrix`, as long as the dimensions/shapes are larger than the index in the list.

Comment: @Psidom, i got the idea. Sorry, can't upvote you answer once more ;-)

Comment: @Psidom in your first result matrix i saw a 7*7 matrix but i expect to see a 3*3 matrix. but after writing the second part of your code it converts to a 3*3 pleasant shape. thanx

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [185]: a,b,c = zip(*A)

In [186]: np.array(a).reshape(np.unique(b).size, -1)
Out[186]:
array([['a_00', 'a_01', 'a_02', 'a_03'],
       ['a_10', 'a_11', 'a_12', 'a_13'],
       ['a_20', 'a_21', 'a_22', 'a_23'],
       ['a_30', 'a_31', 'a_32', 'a_33']],
      dtype='<U4')
```